# I am trying to upgrade a soap based web service which is using tomcat 7 and jdk 1.7 to tomcat version 8.5 and same jdk version

Tags: soap, tomcat7, axis, java-7, tomcat8

the webservice is using Apache axis version 1.4 for the installation. the current version of tomcat that is 7.0.104 which supports until jdk 1.7 and there is no issue while I am trying to install the webservice using the same. But usually when I am trying to do it using tomcat version 8.5 and axis1.4 I am facing the issue.

```
29-Jan-2024 08:09:49.660 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml Parse error in application web.xml file at [file:/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.98/webapps/axis/WEB-INF/web.xml]
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [null] with public ID [-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web
Application 2.3//EN], system ID [http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd] and base URI [null] to a known, local entity.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.LocalResolver.resolveEntity(LocalResolver.java:151)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.LocalResolver.resolveEntity(LocalResolver.java:73)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester$EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Digester.java:2048)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.pushExternalDTD(NonValidatingParser.java:497)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDoctypeDecl(NonValidatingParser.java:455)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseProlog(NonValidatingParser.java:288)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:267)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1496)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1068)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:780)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1179)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1934)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
29-Jan-2024 08:09:49.666 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
29-Jan-2024 08:09:49.666 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
29-Jan-2024 08:09:49.674 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/axis] startup failed due to previous errors
29-Jan-2024 08:09:49.679 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.98/webapps/axis] has finished in [168] ms
29-Jan-2024 08:09:49.681 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8377"]
29-Jan-2024 08:09:49.692 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 725 ms
```

The same thing when I try to install the webservice using tomcat7 and axis1.4 it works without any further issues and also as mentioned in the stack trace that it is unable to parse the web.xml but when I am using tomcat 7 it is working with same web.xml file that is present in the axis WEB-INF folder.
I am unable to understand whether this is the only issue that is not letting the axis client to start or is it some other issue. Can anyone provide any kind of input on how to make an approach to resolve the issue. Is there any dependency on the tomcat newer version (here 8.5) for axis 1.4 to work.

Comment: Stop using outdated java 7 , tomcat 7 and tomcat 8, all of them are very old and as I know EOL since many years

Comment: Jens thanks for your input . What do you suggest can be used here so that i can proceed with it and don't encounter such an exception like this .